# Performing sum of dice and generating the percentage with histogram

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to generate a program of rolling rice and adding the resulting numbers and outputting the histogram of these sums
For example `dice(trials, numbers)` . If I give `dice(10,5)` it means that i am rolling a 5 `dice` 10 times.

My output should be something in this pattern:

```
12 : 2 : **
20 : 1 : * 
25 : 0 : 
18 : 3 : ***
19 : 0 :
10 : 0 :
14 : 1 : *
25 : 0 :
29 : 5 : *****
30 : 7 : *******
```

where the first column is the number (since it is 5 and the random number can be any number between 5 to 30. because if we roll a dice and sum them the minimum number we can obtain is `5` `(1+1+1+1+1)` and max is `30` `(6+6+6+6+6)`. Since the trials is 10 we have 10 rows. And the second column being the number of occurrences of that number and the third being the histogram of occurences.

Can anyone please help me doing this?
I have a similar program which i am trying to modify with this..

```
walks(trials,steps) :
finalcount= { position :0 for position in range(-steps,steps+1)) 
for _ in range(trials): 
    finalcount[Randomwalk(steps)]+=1 
Histogram({position : round(finalcount[position]*100/trials)
           for position in finalcount})

def Randomwalk(steps): 
position=0 
for _ in range(steps): 
    direction=choice("<>") 
    if direction == "<": 
       position-=1 
    else : 
       position +=1 
return position

def Histogram(d):
keylist=sorted(d)
lo=keylist[0]
while d[lo]==0:
    lo+=1
hi=keylist[-1]
while d[hi]==0
    hi -=1
for k in range (lo,hi+1):
    print("%3i : %3i : %s" % (k,d[k],d[k]*"*"))
```

Comment: Come on, have you tried something? Show us the code you have and tell us where you are having problems.

Comment: I have one similar program. I am trying to modify it.

Comment: I have one similar program. I am trying to modify it. walks(trials,steps) finalcount= { position :0 for position in range(-steps,steps+1)) for _ in range(trials): finalcount[Randomwalk(steps)]+=1 and the randomwalk is something like this Randomwalk(steps): position=0 for _ in range(steps): direction=choice("<>") if direction == "<": position-=1 else : position +=1 return position. Sorry i am giving my sample code in comment.

Comment: Don't post is as a comment (because it is not readable). Edit your post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
from random import randint

def dice(trials, numbers):
    results = {} #createe empty dictionary
    for throw in range(trials):
        thrown = randint(1, numbers)
        try:
            results[thrown] += 1
        except:
            results[thrown] = 1
    return results

def histogram(d):
    keylist=sorted(d)
    lo=keylist[0]
    while d[lo]==0:
        lo+=1
    hi=keylist[-1]
    while d[hi]==0:
        hi -=1
    for k in range (lo,hi+1):
        print("%3i : %3i : %s" % (k,d[k],d[k]*"*"))

histogram(dice(10, 6))
```

If you are allowed to use [counters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), you can make it less clumsy:

```
from collections import Counter

def dice(trials, numbers):
    results = Counter()
    for throw in range(trials):
        results[randint(1, numbers)] += 1
    return results
```

And I just copied your histogram-code. You won't need the two while loops since only values which were thrown are added to the dictionary / counter:

```
def histogram(d):        
    #for k in d: #use this one if you don't want to display empty values
    for k in range(min(d), max(d)+1):  #use that one to start at the minium number thrown and display zeros for empty values
        print("%3i : %3i : %s" % (k,d[k],d[k]*"*"))
```

Here comes an updated version based on the comments / clarification of the question:

```
def mod_dice(trials, numbers):
    """A dice with 6 faces is thrown "numbers" times in each "trial"."""
    results = Counter()
    for attempt in range(trials):
        sum = 0
        for throw in range(numbers):
            sum += randint(1, 6)
        results[sum] += 1
    return results
```

which gives a nice plot if you start it e.g. with 500, 5:

```
  7 :   1 : *
  8 :   2 : **
  9 :   5 : *****
 10 :   8 : ********
 11 :  11 : ***********
 12 :  13 : *************
 13 :  28 : ****************************
 14 :  41 : *****************************************
 15 :  46 : **********************************************
 16 :  47 : ***********************************************
 17 :  45 : *********************************************
 18 :  65 : *****************************************************************
 19 :  51 : ***************************************************
 20 :  33 : *********************************
 21 :  31 : *******************************
 22 :  19 : *******************
 23 :  26 : **************************
 24 :  14 : **************
 25 :   9 : *********
 26 :   1 : *
 27 :   2 : **
 28 :   1 : *
 29 :   1 : *
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it is giving 1 to 6 in the first column.I am trying to get a pattern similar to the ones that i have mentioned in the question. i.e first column should be any random number from 6 to 30 if u give the number as 5. and it is any random number between 6 to 36 if you give the number as 6 and so on..

Comment: Hmmm, your example makes it clearer, but your sentence "If I give dice(10,5) it means that i am rolling a 5 dice 10 times." made me think I have a dice with 5 faces and this one is rolles 10 times. You should correct your question while I update the answer ;)